# Pose Mode: How to reset transformed armature to its rest position?

Tags: armature, transforms

I got a problem with pose mode. 
Like the heading says, I haven't found yet a possibility to **reset the already transformed armature so that it exactly does look like the rest position** (though it is still in pose position). 
 
Is there any kind of shortcuts or tricks to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to select all bones, then hit "ALT+R" to reset all rotations, and "ALT+G" to reset all translations, and "ALT+S" to reset all scales? If you do that and it doesn't return to its rest position, it means you may have errors in the bone constraints (dependency cycle).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Select all the bones, in **pose mode** with <kbd>A</kbd>. Then, hit:

- <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to reset all rotations,
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to reset all translations,
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to reset all scales.

Or, you can select all bones (<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>space</kbd>. Then search for "clear pose" and select **Clear Pose Transforms** in the results. Et voilà!

Mac Users Use <kbd>Option</kbd> instead of <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

Comment: Note that the pose will revert if you have an animation applied. This only works if you remove all animations first.

Comment: At this moment when importing FBX files with an armature (which I purchased online), Blender 2.8X imports the bones rotations with the wrong format, making it look all broken. Then I noticed how the bones were "recovering" their right position when looking up the armature and then, in pose mode, return to their broken position. Your answer (ALT+R) is what fixed it for me so thanks a lot!

Comment: This alone wasn't the full solution for me. It took me some time to realize that before resetting I also have to **make all bone layers visible**, which can be done in Object Data Properties panel -> Armature -> Layers.

Answer (score 9):

Case of the Hidden Bones.

If someone else is finding this problem, the above solution does work except....
If you have some bones hidden from view they will not be selected and therefore they will not be reset.  I spent more than an hour and I was only minutes away from flipping my desk when I realized some of the bones were hidden.  So unhide those bones and make sure they are part of the selection when you reset everything.

Comment: I just had the same issue 

Comment: I had a similar problem where I'd added some IK bones, whose default positions were way off what they should have been, so after clearing all transforms they were stretching everything out like crazy. Had to turn off all IK constraints, then enable and fix them one by one.

Comment: You're the MVP!

Comment: The Clear User Transforms with Only Selected unchecked in the right click menu of pose mode will reset hidden bones too.

Answer (score 6):

In case the above doesn't solve your problem, I found myself having similar issues because I had bones constrained to a pole target and my pole angle was off. I'm not sure why this displays differently in rest mode vs pose mode, and that's what was driving me crazy and acting as a red herring.

Answer (score 3):

### To reset all hidden and unselected bones in an armature:

1. Enter pose mode
2. Right click in the viewport and select "Clear User Transforms"
3. Uncheck "Only Selected" in its options

[image: The Pose Context Menu]

[image: Clear User Transforms Options]

Answer (score 1):

[image: I tried to reset rest pose, but there were some contraints missing. It's just a picture of an extrem buggy step in between but, that result could be fixed just with more contraints]

There is another issue, which comes up by complex rigs with multiple bones, like arms which have three pairs of bones.

One pair for inverse kinematic, one for forward kinematic and one pair which effects the mesh.

If there are not every bone corectly set with contraints, especialy with copy location contrains, there might be some differences between edit and pose mode.

Comment: Are you implying that in such a case there is no definitive rest pose?

Comment: in such an setup as it was at my complex rig, the bones restet in another location as from edit mode, yes. But I did a extremly complex rig with an DVD Workshop.

Comment: This is the start of an important bit of information not contained in other answers, but only the start-- it may be necessary to delete constraints to achieve your rest pose (unless you just manually set it to 'rest'.)  Constraints act almost just like transformations.   Many constraints other than IK can do this however; exactly which depend not only on the constraint, but on its settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution that might evade a person.  The bones must be set to Axis | Angle rather than Quaternion Rotation. This happened to me when exporting from Makehuman 1.1.1 to Blender 2.76b

Comment: This answer is not complete. My rigs are posable and resetable regardless of the rotation mode.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that is simple and might be helpful so I post this in this old thread.

When working on a Rigify armature I got a similar problem. Even with all bones unhidden, also all constraints deleted with menu search (f3) > clear pose constraints so I was sure there where no constraints on any bones. The Torso-bone did not want to go in rest pose.

What worked for me:

1. In pose mode go to your Armature properties tab in the properties editor.
2. In the Skeleton section choose *Rest Position*
3. Create a new action in the Dope Sheet > Action Editor
4. Insert a keyframe (with I in the viewport) at frame 1 with loc/rot/scale. I chose
   Visual loc/rot/scale but I do not know if that is needed so try both at will
5. Give the action a name, for example forced_restpose and give it a fake user so you can
   use it later (with the shield icon next to the name)
6. Go back to *Pose Position* in the Armature properties tab
7. Select all the bones in your armature again
8. Select the action you just made
9. Got to the keyframe you just created. Sometimes going a frame to the left or right
   from your keyframe and back helps
10. If all went well your model now is in the "rest pose"
11. Remove the action (forced_restpose) from the action editor by clicking on the x next
    to the name)