# Export rest pose to unity as default action

Tags: animation

[image]I'm trying to export my model to unity.
I've made low poly character and animated it with idle, walkF, walkR, walkL and walkB animations.
After exporting to unity as .fbx file or .blend file the character won't stay i T-pose. It sees its walkL(walk left) animation as its default action.
In a fact I don't want no action to be default. By default I want my character to stay in T-pose.
Please, I'm helpless...

Comment: Suggest making a "dummy" T-pose  action.  Clear all [using methods outlined here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30913/15543) which "Should" with no IK, result in the rest pose, and insert a locrot keyframe for all bones.  (looking in graph editor these will all be zero)

Comment: @batFINGER I did it, but the action is not default for my model. It's like walkL is default action for my character and after exporting model or restarting blender, my character gets back to WalkL action even it is not opened in action editor. thx anyway :/

Comment: I don't have unity to check, but my guess would be put the blank action in the same location as your walk action (whichever one is default in unity, looks like it's top in NLA stack, use move strip up and down) and try exporting again.,

Comment: @batFINGER yeaaaah it works. It's not exactly what I imagined, but it may works now. Thx alot batFINGER

Comment: Write it up as an answer. Be useful to others. 8*) .. suggest change question title to _"Export rest pose to unity as default action"_ or some such..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set T pose as rest position and created action with only one keyframe(in T pose). Called it "default"(it was first in alphabetical order. This caused that action was default and even if I closed every action opened, the character jumped to T pose as normally. Even in unity it seems like normal model in T pose. The only thing is one extra action. This is forgivable.

Answer (score 0):

Select your character > click the pose data property tab >
Skeleton > Rest Position > reset the rest position
[Pose Mode: How to reset transformed armature to its rest position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30881/pose-mode-how-to-reset-transformed-armature-to-its-rest-position#30913)

[image: pose]

Comment: your answer almost made my day, but unfortunately after resetting the rest pose my character stay in the rest pose even if I want to play animation. When I switch back to Pose position, the character won't stay in t pose. None of both are good for unity :/ but thx anyway

Comment: The rest position should just be a T or some other neutral position.  Your pose positions should be whatever action(s) you decide upon.  Why wouldn't that work in Unity?

Comment: it's not that it doesn't work just in unity. If I restart blender or open and then close some action, my character goes back to walkL action, what is also default action in unity :/

Comment: I've created an action with T pose at frame 0 and it was created on the top in NLA editor somehow. It works. Thx alot :)