# Impossible to restore armature's pose

Tags: armature, constraints, pose-mode

I want the pose to be identical as the rest pose. I've cleared all transformations of my armature in pose mode but it's still not the same as the rest pose. I'm sure it's related to specific constraints and pole targets but I don't know how to fix it. This didn't help me [Pose Mode: How to reset transformed armature to its rest position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30881/pose-mode-how-to-reset-transformed-armature-to-its-rest-position) Why is it so hard for blender to do this simple thing?

Comment: Please upload your file, or it's impossible to answer